# Append Header and Trailer Files with Detail file

Tags: shell-script

I have 3 files created with the following names. Both Header and Trailer contains one record every time.

Input Files :

Header.txt
Detail.txt
Trailer.txt

I need to copy record from header and insert at the first record of Detail record and also copy record from trailer and insert at the end of Detail record.

Input :

Header.txt

> HD

Detail.txt

> D1
>   D2
>   D3
>   D4

Trailer.txt

> TR

Expected output:

Output.txt

> HD
>   D1
>   D2
>   D3
>   D4
>   TR

Comment: `cat Header.txt Detail.txt Trailer.txt`

Comment: welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat Header.txt Detail.txt Trailer.txt >Output.txt
```

This would create the file `Output.txt` that would be the concatenation of the three files in the order given on the command line (assuming that the output file is able to be created and/or written to).